# RecyclerView not showing items. In Java works fine in Kotlin not

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying to follow the same way of implementation as I did with Java. But for some reason its not working. Debugger shows that program doesn't even go inside adapter.

Activity code

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    lateinit var input: EditText
    lateinit var button : Button
    lateinit var recycler : RecyclerView
    lateinit var adapter: MyRecyclerViewAdapter

    var data : List<Animal> = listOf()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("First", "Second"))
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("111", "222"))
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("444", "333"))
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("First", "Second"))
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("111", "222"))
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("444", "333"))
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("First", "Second"))
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("111", "222"))
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("444", "333"))
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("First", "Second"))
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("111", "222"))
        data.toMutableList().add(Animal("444", "333"))

        input = findViewById(R.id.edit)
        button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler)
        adapter = MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, data)

        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter.setOnClickListener(this)
        recycler.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
    class MyRecyclerViewAdapter(private val context : Context, private val mData : List<Animal>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    lateinit var mClickListener : ItemClickListener
    var mInflater : LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mData.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val name : String = mData[position].name
        val last : String = mData[position].last
        holder.mName.text = name
        holder.mLast.text = last
    }

    fun getItem(id : Int) : Animal{
        return mData[id]
    }

    fun setOnClickListener(itemClickListener : ItemClickListener){
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener
    }

    interface ItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(view : View, position: Int)
    }
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
         var mName : TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvAnimalName)
         var mLast : TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvAnimalLastName)

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
val data = mutableListOf<Animal>() 

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    data.add(Animal("First", "Second"))
    data.add(Animal("111", "222"))
    data.add(Animal("444", "333"))
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you it works. But can you please clarify. Why do we use val here instead of var?

Comment: The reference to the list object remains the same although the contents are not

Comment: You should always prefer `val` if the object instance is not re-assigned later.

Answer (score 0):

change the way you populating that list

```
val data : List<Animal> = listOf(
            Animal("First", "Second"),
            Animal("111", "222"),
            Animal("444", "333"),
            Animal("First", "Second"),
            Animal("111", "222"),
            Animal("444", "333"),
            Animal("First", "Second"),
            Animal("111", "222"),
            Animal("444", "333")
            )
```

**Also Note**

1. avoid using variables that look like reserved word eg. use AnimalHolder instead of ViewHolder
2. populate the views in the viewholder, not in the adapter I have added a function Bind

### MyRecyclerViewAdapter

```
package com.example.kotlin

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

 class MyRecyclerViewAdapter(private val context : Context, private val animals : List<Animal>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.AnimalHolder>() {

    lateinit var mClickListener: ItemClickListener
    var mInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AnimalHolder {
        val view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false)
        return AnimalHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount()= animals.size


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AnimalHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(animals[position])
    }

    fun getItem(id: Int): Animal {
        return animals[id]
    }

    fun setOnClickListener(itemClickListener: ItemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener
    }

    interface ItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int)
    }
     class AnimalHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        private lateinit var animal: Animal
        val mName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAnimalName)
        val mLast: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAnimalLastName)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        fun bind(animal: Animal) {
            this.animal = animal
            mName.text = this.animal.name
            mLast.text = this.animal.last
            Log.d("0001", "Total crimes: ${this.animal.last}")
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        }
    }

}
```

### MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.kotlin

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    lateinit var input: EditText
    lateinit var button : Button
    lateinit var recycler : RecyclerView
    lateinit var adapter: MyRecyclerViewAdapter



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val data : List<Animal> = listOf(
            Animal("First", "Second"),
            Animal("111", "222"),
            Animal("444", "333"),
            Animal("First", "Second"),
            Animal("111", "222"),
            Animal("444", "333"),
            Animal("First", "Second"),
            Animal("111", "222"),
            Animal("444", "333")
            )
        input = findViewById(R.id.edit)
        button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler)
        adapter = MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, data)

        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter.setOnClickListener(this)
        recycler.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```